# Laravel 3 debug php ajax firePHP

Tags: php, ajax, debugging, laravel, firephp

I have few questions:

Is there a better alternative for firePHP, for displaying server-side logs in developer console in the browser(agnostic: firefox, chrome..)  (for ajax debugging)?

What is the best way to use firePHP in Laravel?
Do I include it in "public/index.php" or in paths or in the controller? Or does it autoloads somehow?
What manipulation laravel does (to headers etc) similar to firePHP, are there any collisions to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/fireanbu) for using firephp in laravel. You can use it.

Comment: Nice, just found out about bundles.
What ANBU stands for??

Comment: firePHP did not work for me in chrome, i tried diffrerent plugins non worked for some reason. so this one worked, may be usefull for people
[http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/chromephp]

Comment: you'll find thats wrong. anyway its so old, using clockwork for laravel 4